# Der, das oder die „Club-Mate“?

Tags: gender

Auf der [offizielle Seite lautet](http://www.clubmate.de/was-ist-club-mate.html) „*die* Mate“:

> Die Mate nützt dem Körper, denn in jeder Flasche Club-Mate befindet sich ein voller Teelöffel Mate-Tee. Club-Mate ist darum der Zunge ein Genuß, dem Körper ein Bedürfnis.

Muttersprachler nutzten auch im Gespräch *die*.

Club-Mate ist keinesfalls so wichtig wie Joghurt, dessen Geschlecht nicht gleichmäßig verwendet wird (im Bundesdeutschen [*der*, ansonsten *das* Joghurt](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-4/f24a-g/)). Dafür ist aber [*Mate* ein männliches Nomen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mate) und das verwirrt mich.

- Ist anerkannt, dass das Geschlecht von *(Club-)Mate* nicht gleichmäßig verwendet wird, oder ist es schlicht falsch, wenn ich es als männliches Nomen – welches mehr Sinn ergibt – nutze?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Wiktionaryseite, die du dankenswerterweise verlinkt hast, listet zwei mögliche Geschlechter auf: *den* Mate für den Tee und *die* Mate für die Pflanze. Die Brause »Club-Mate« ist freundlicherweise nicht dabei.

Ich würde mich ein wenig aus dem Fenster lehnen, und behaupten, dass *Mate*, wenn die Brause gemeint ist, gar kein wirklich definiertes Geschlecht hat; aber am ehesten ein *die* (und in Österreich wahrscheinlich *das*) verwendet würde, analog zu *der Cola, der Sprite* und *der Fanta* (Dativ!).

Du könntest natürlich von *der Mate-Limonade* oder *der Mate-Brause* oder *dem Mate-Getränk* reden, damit Eindeutigkeit reinkommt. Oder du benutzt ausschließlich den bairischen Nominativ mit schwachem unbestimmten Artikel: *a Mate*.

Comment: In Österreich ist tatsächlich am ehesten *das*, analog zu *dem* Cola, *dem* Sprite und *dem* Fanta.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich wollte schon einen Klammerkommentar dazuschreiben à la »wie Hubert sicherlich bald bestätigen wird« oder so ;)

Comment: Mich irritiert es ja immer wieder, wenn "Brause" für Getränke verwendet wird, die nicht aus Brausepulver hergestellt werden.^^

Comment: Ist vielleicht Limo gemeint?

Comment: @userunknown ist die Frage, inwiefern man eine Club-Mate als Limo einstufen kann oder nicht. Ich trinke beides nicht, weil ich keine Kohlensäure mag ;)

Comment: Jan: Ja, ich hätte meinem Kommentar ein @Chris voranstellen sollen; dass es keine Brause ist.

Answer (score 2):

Bedenke, nach den Regeln für zusammengesetzte Substantive gilt: Wenn „Mate“ männlich ist, dann muss auch „Club-Mate“ männlich sein.

Dass „Mate“ tatsächlich männlich ist und sein muss, darf bezweifelt werden.